# Android WebChrome Client Promts/Opens Link in browser rather than WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, webchromeclient

Upon launch of the activity, the webview should load the designated url but in the simulator it launches the native browser and on the physical device it prompts to open the url in in the browser.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://google.com");
}
```

Trying to get it so that the webview neither launches in native browser or prompts the user to open in browser. Also all embedded links should stay in the webview if clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to implement the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method:

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you don't add a WebViewClient to your WebView instance. In order to enable navigation in the same WebView, you need to set a WebViewClient to your WebView instance wv. Add the following line:

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: So I add that line and also keep the line wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: Yes. Set both the clients.

Comment: I'm assuming this solved your issue. Can you please mark the answer as accepted? If it hasn't, do let me know.